# Office add-in - on key pressed - installer

Tags: ms-office, office-addins, office-js

I would like to develop an office add-in for Microsoft Word using HTML5/Javascript API and I need your help with the following questions:

1. Does the Word Javascript API have an event for "on key pressed"? so any time the user is typing in the document I will be able to catch that event on my add-in?
2. Is it possible to install a Word Add-in directly without using the office store? so I can bundle my add-in into my own installer (for example NSIS installer)

Thanks
Shai

Comment: These two questions are unrelated to each other. I'll answer the first here. Please edit and create a new post for the second. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no API for on on-key-pressed event.

The closest option is the [DocumentSelectionChanged](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.selectionchanged.event) API event, which fires every time the user's selection changes. In Word, this event fires on some key presses, such as:

- Any arrow key press
- Enter
- Tab
- Clicking to position the cursor in the document (not a key press)
- The first key press of any kind (letter, number, etc.) that immediately follows one of the above types of key press.

Here's the sample:

```js
var doc = Office.context.document;
doc.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged, function(eventArgs){
    // do something when the selection changes
});
```

-Michael Saunders, program manager for Office add-ins

Comment: Thanks for your great answer :)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 2022

The example of Michael Saunders is still working, but it covers also other keys, making it much more useful; basically the event fires everytime the cursor moves:

- any letter
- any number
- any punctuation or special character
- backspace
- spacebar

what is still not handled is any key which doesn't make the cursor move:

- del
- shift
- any dead key (since they only modify the next-coming character)

Tested on Word 365 (Version 2208)